# Why do we need `ngDoCheck`

Tags: angular, angular2-docheck

I can't seem to figure out why I need `ngDoCheck` lifecycle hook other than for simple notification, particularly how writing code inside of it makes a difference as regard to change detection. Most of the examples I've found show useless examples, like [this one](https://juristr.com/blog/2016/04/angular2-change-detection/), with a bunch of logging functionality.

Also, in the generated classes I don't see it being used for something else other than simple notification:

**`conmponent/wrapper.ngfactory.js`**

```js
Wrapper_AppComponent.prototype.ngDoCheck = function(view,el,throwOnChange) {
  var self = this;
  var changed = self._changed;
  self._changed = false;
  if (!throwOnChange) {
    if (changed) {
      jit_setBindingDebugInfoForChanges1(view.renderer,el,self._changes);
      self._changes = {};
    }
    self.context.ngDoCheck(); <----------- this calls ngDoCheck on the component
                                               but the result is not used 
                                               anywhere and no params are passed
  }
  return changed;
};
```

Answer (score 102, accepted):

This great article [If you think `ngDoCheck` means your component is being checked — read this article](https://indepth.dev/if-you-think-ngdocheck-means-your-component-is-being-checked-read-this-article) explains the error in depth.

The contents of this answer is based on the angular version 2.x.x. For the most recent version 4.x.x see [this post](https://indepth.dev/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular).

There is nothing on the internet on the inner workings of change detection, so I had to spend about a week debugging sources, so this answer will be pretty technical on details.

An angular application is a tree of [views](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/80fe41a88ecc90ab8b08318c6bee0238b2f5f46d/modules/%40angular/core/src/linker/view.ts) (`AppView` class that is extended by the Component specific class generated by the compiler). Each view has a change detection mode that lives in `cdMode` property. The default value for `cdMode` is `ChangeDetectorStatus.CheckAlways`, which is `cdMode = 2`.

When a change detection cycle runs, each parent view checks whether it should perform change detection on the child view [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/80fe41a88ecc90ab8b08318c6bee0238b2f5f46d/modules/%40angular/core/src/linker/view.ts#L321):

```js
      detectChanges(throwOnChange: boolean): void {
        const s = _scope_check(this.clazz);
        if (this.cdMode === ChangeDetectorStatus.Checked ||
            this.cdMode === ChangeDetectorStatus.Errored)
          return;
        if (this.cdMode === ChangeDetectorStatus.Destroyed) {
          this.throwDestroyedError('detectChanges');
        }
        this.detectChangesInternal(throwOnChange); <---- performs CD on child view
```

where `this` points to the `child` view. So if `cdMode` is `ChangeDetectorStatus.Checked=1`, the change detection is skipped for the immediate child and all its descendants because of this line.

```js
    if (this.cdMode === ChangeDetectorStatus.Checked ||
            this.cdMode === ChangeDetectorStatus.Errored)
          return;
```

What `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` does is simply sets `cdMode` to `ChangeDetectorStatus.CheckOnce = 0`, so after the first run of change detection the child view will have its `cdMode` set to `ChangeDetectorStatus.Checked = 1` because of [this code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/80fe41a88ecc90ab8b08318c6bee0238b2f5f46d/modules/%40angular/core/src/linker/view.ts#L330):

```js
    if (this.cdMode === ChangeDetectorStatus.CheckOnce) 
         this.cdMode = ChangeDetectorStatus.Checked;
```

Which means that the next time a change detection cycle starts there will be no change detection performed for the child view.

There are few options how to run change detection for such view. First is to change child view's `cdMode` to `ChangeDetectorStatus.CheckOnce`, which can be done using `this._changeRef.markForCheck()` in `ngDoCheck` lifecycle hook:

```js
      constructor(private _changeRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {   }
    
      ngDoCheck() {
        this._changeRef.markForCheck();
      }
```

This simply changes `cdMode` of the current view and its parents to `ChangeDetectorStatus.CheckOnce`, so next time the change detection is performed the current view is checked.

Check a full example [here in the sources](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/80fe41a88ecc90ab8b08318c6bee0238b2f5f46d/modules/%40angular/core/src/change_detection/change_detector_ref.ts#L18), but here is the gist of it:

```js
          constructor(ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
            setInterval(() => {
              this.numberOfTicks ++
              // the following is required, otherwise the view will not be updated
              this.ref.markForCheck();
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            }, 1000);
          }
```

The second option is call `detectChanges` on the view itself which will [run change detection](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/80fe41a88ecc90ab8b08318c6bee0238b2f5f46d/modules/%40angular/core/src/linker/view.ts#L321) on the current view if `cdMode` is not `ChangeDetectorStatus.Checked` or `ChangeDetectorStatus.Errored`. Since with `onPush` angular sets `cdMode` to `ChangeDetectorStatus.CheckOnce`, angular will run the change detection.

So `ngDoCheck` doesn't override the changed detection, it's simply called on every changed detection cycle and it's only job is to set current view `cdMode` as `checkOnce`, so that during next change detection cycle it's checked for the changes. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42807309/2545680) for details. If the current view's change detection mode is `checkAlways` (set by default if onPush strategy is not used), `ngDoCheck` seem to be of no use.

Answer (score 20):

The `DoCheck` interface is used to detect changes manually which the angular change detection have overlooked. A use could be when you change the `ChangeDetectionStrategy` of your component, but you know that one property of an object will change.

**It's more efficient to check for this one change, than to let the changeDetector run through your entire component**

```js
let obj = {
  iChange = 'hiii'
}
```

If you use `obj.iChange` inside your template, angular will not detect it if this value changes, because the reference of `obj` itself doesn't change. You need to implement an `ngDoCheck` to check if the value has changed, and call a `detectChanges` on your component's changeDetector.

From the angular documentation about [`DoCheck`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#docheck)

> While the `ngDoCheck` hook can detect when the hero's name has changed, it has a frightful cost. This hook is called with enormous frequency — after every change detection cycle no matter where the change occurred. It's called over twenty times in this example before the user can do anything.
>
> Most of these initial checks are triggered by Angular's first rendering of unrelated data elsewhere on the page. Mere mousing into another input box triggers a call. Relatively few calls reveal actual changes to pertinent data. Clearly our implementation must be very lightweight or the user experience will suffer.

**tested example**

```js
@Component({
   selector: 'test-do-check',
   template: `
      <div [innerHtml]="obj.changer"></div>
   `, 
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class TestDoCheckComponent implements DoCheck, OnInit {
    public obj: any = {
       changer: 1
    };
    
    private _oldValue: number = 1;
   
    constructor(private _changeRef: ChangeDetectorRef){}
    
    ngOnInit() {
       setInterval(() => {
          this.obj.changer += 1;
       }, 1000);
    }
    
    ngDoCheck() {
       if(this._oldValue !== this.obj.changer) {
          this._oldValue = this.obj.changer;

               //disable this line to see the counter not moving
           this._changeRef.detectChanges();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but I still don't understand. Your answer seems to be about `ngDoChanges`. How is it related to `ngDoCheck`?

Comment: @Maximus what PierreDuc meant if you **don't** use `DoCheck`, you need to trigger change detection manually if the object ref doesn't change.

Comment: @echonax, that's even more confusing. Maybe you can show an elaborate example?

Comment: @Maximus my example is about `DoCheck`. `OnChanges` is triggered when the angular change detector actually detects a change. `DoCheck` is used to manually detect changes which the angular changedetector will overlook

Comment: @PierreDuc, okay, can you please provide the `ngDoCheck` implementation for your example?

Comment: I've added an example, although i did not test it. But i believe if you disable the `ngDoCheck` method, the value will not update

Comment: @PierreDuc, thanks, now it's more clear. So basically I'm required to call ` this._changeRef.detectChanges();` inside the method if value changed, correct? By the way, just tried the code, the counter doesn't get updated. Maybe take a look please?

Comment: Yes, if you manually detected a change, you need to call the changeDetector to update the component. I tried to code as well, before you replied, and it does work for me. The value updates now.. if i remove the `detectChanges` it does not

Comment: @PierreDuc, okay, thanks. It doesn't work for me however. I'll go explore the sources to understand how it works then. But `this._changeRef.detectChanges();` is probably what was missing in my understanding.

Comment: @PierreDuc, can you please take a look at [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/WR1uwIhQzYjD8m78SWyl?p=preview)? The counter is not updated there as well

Comment: @Maximus you need to remove `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` line inside the `@Component` annotation in `TestDoCheckComponent` Fixed plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/lwy2bcCVS1CwEtGlsYfq?p=preview

Comment: @echonax that will not show a use-case of `DoCheck`. It's weird though, I can simulate it fine on my own project, but yes, in the plunkr it doesn't seem to work. As far as I know there should be a `DoCheck` after the interval, regardless of the `ChangeDetectionStrategy`. Note though that I am working with the latest angular 4 version

Comment: @PierreDuc I totally understand your point but it seems that when we use `OnPush`, it ignores the `DoCheck` changes in the template :/ (I just wanted to fix the plunker :P)

Comment: @PierreDuc, sorry, but I had to revoke my acceptance from your answer since it's a bit incorrect. I've upvoted though since you pointed me in the right direction with the requirements to call a method inside `doCheck`. I've spent a week figuring out the internals and please see my findings [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42807309/2545680).

Comment: @echonax, check out my correct answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42807309/2545680)

Comment: @echonax, sure, I'll let you know once I have my article published. You can follow [me on medium](https://medium.com/@maximus.koretskyi).

Comment: @echonax, published an article on changed detection [here](https://hackernoon.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f), you might want to check it out

Answer (score 10):

**Note:**

The default algorithm of angular for change detection looks for differences by comparing input-bound properties value by reference, understand. Cool.

**Limitation of ngOnChanges()**

Due to default behavior of angular change detection, ngOnChanges can't detect if someone changes a property of an object or push an item into  array  .
So ngDoCheck comes to recuse.

**ngDoCheck()  wow!**

Detect deep changes like a property change in object or item is pushed into array even without reference change. Amazing Right

Answer (score 6):

In simple terms :

> It's generally a component check on following occasions:
>
> - Update child component input bindings
> - Update DOM interpolations
> - Update query list

Use :

> Deep Watch changes which angular misses out.

Answer (score 0):

I used it today and case was the following.
I had a complex object array MyItem[].
In my template I used a ngFor to iterate over it and generate a component.

Every template generate inside the ngFor had buttons for moving the current location on up or down.

This worked great for the pressed component but not for the siblings.

With ngDoCheck I did the following:

```
ngDoCheck(): void
{
   // this life cycle will check if one of your sibling steps changed the order and update the view 
   // otherwise siblings views will not be updated and keep there previous DOM element
   if(this.stepItem?.stepNo && this.stepItem.stepNo != this.currentStepNo)
   {
       this.currentStepNo = this.stepItem.stepNo;
       this.cd.detectChanges();
   }
}
```

With that the other components effected will be rerendered.