# specific use case for ngDocheck and ngOnchanges

Tags: angular

Is there any specific use case for ngDocheck and ngOnchanges. I read this  [blog](https://blog.angularindepth.com/if-you-think-ngdocheck-means-your-component-is-being-checked-read-this-article-36ce63a3f3e5) and I got to know that the framework uses these events in change detection and all. Is there any specific scenario where we use these events please help me in understanding this. Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have an important input parameter in your component that determines the logic to be used. When this parameter changes, you want to call initialization logic.

```js
export class Component implements OnChanges {
    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
        if (changes.importantParameter) {
            this.initialize();
        }
    }

    constructor(private api: API) {}

    public initialize() {
        this.api.getData(this.importantParameter);
    }

    @Input()
    public importantParameter: string;
}
```

The `changes` object also gives your access to the current and previous value of the object.

For `ngDoCheck`, this answer offers a great explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42807309/9628950