# From an array of objects making an array of subobjects

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array of JavaScript objects in one of my components

```
@Component(stuff)
export class ComponentName {
  arrayOfObjects = [];
  // stuff
}
```

in which each object has the keys `key1` and `key2`.

What I would like is to have an array `arrayOfSubobjects` in `ComponentName` whose contents are

```
{
  key1: 'value1',
  key2: 'value2'
}
```

for each pair of `key1` and `key2` that reside within the same object in `arrayOfObjects`.

Moreover, if the value of `key1` updates within an object in `arrayOfObjects`, it has to be reflected in `arrayOfSubobjects`. Same thing with `key2`.

Note that `arrayOfObjects` is subject to losing/gaining objects.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `map` method. A Javascript feature that iterates over the given array, works similar to `forEach` and will return a value at the end of the loop.

```
let arrayofSubobjects;

reduceTheArray(): void {
   this.arrayofSubobjects = arrayOfObjects.map(ele => {key1: ele.key1, key2: ele.key2});
}
```

I've declared the `arrayofSubobjects` as a global variable and used it inside a function to store the filtered value.
Implemented using typescript syntax (tags).

Comment: This looks like it would only make `arrayOfSubobjects` correspond to `arrayOfObjects` once; it doesn't look like `arrayOfSubojects` would update dynamically. Am I wrong?

Comment: For a dynamic update, the given function `reduceTheArray` can be manually triggered inside the angular life cycle method `ngDoCheck`.
Follow the solution like in here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42643506/10003927

Answer (score 0):

In order to have the values dynamically update you need to point to the same reference.

I wonder why not just create an interface that only exposes key1, key2 and use the same array.

At any rate, if I understand your requirements I think something like this will work:

```
interface ComplicatedObject {
    key1: string;
    key2: string;
}

class SubObject {
    private complicatedObject: ComplicatedObject;

    constructor(complicatedObject: ComplicatedObject) {
        this.complicatedObject = complicatedObject;
    }

    get key1(): string {
        return this.complicatedObject.key1;
    }

    get key2(): string {
        return this.complicatedObject.key2;
    }
}

describe('Testing ComplicatedObject -> SubObject', () => {
    it('should update key1 on SubObject when Complicated Object changes', () => {
        const obj: ComplicatedObject = {
            key1: '1',
            key2: '2'
        };

        const sub: SubObject = new SubObject(obj);

        expect(sub.key1).toBe(obj.key1);
        expect(sub.key2).toBe(obj.key2);

        obj.key1 = 'edited';
        obj.key2 = 'edited as well';
        expect(sub.key1).toBe(obj.key1);
        expect(sub.key2).toBe(obj.key2);
    });
});
```